# What is the mathematical derivation for Ordinal Logistic Regression from Logit Function?

Tags: classification, mathematical-statistics, ordered-logit

I'd like to understand the mathematical background of Ordinal Logistic Regression to derive from Logit Function. I understand how to derive Multinomial Logistic Regression but I am kind of confused of the concept of derivation of Multinomial Logistic Regression from Logit Fuction. Maybe I don't really understand the concept of Ordinal Logistic Regression.

Can somebody show me the derivation for Ordinal Logistic Regression from Logit Function? If you can add some explanations, that would help me even better.